# asyncio.wait in OOP design

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an application where my operations are network bound so I would like to execute these data pulls asynchronously.

I make multiple data pulls to AWS, which is in the `pull` method. In the `runApplication` method, I use `asyncio.wait` for each of the two tasks.

```py
import asyncio

class Application:

   def __init__(self, A, B):
      self.A = A
      self.B = B 

   async def pull(self, stuff):
      result = aws.get_stuff(stuff) 
      return await result 
   
   def applicationLogic(self):
      pass 

   async def aws_wrapper(self):
      self.aPull = self.pull(self.A)
      self.bPull = self.pull(self.B)
      tasks = [self.aPull, self.bPull]
      await asyncio.wait(tasks)

   def aws_async_executor(self):
      asyncio.run(self.aws_wrapper) 
      self.applicationLogic()
```

The application is failing because the `applicationLogic` method requires that `tasks` have been completed prior to execution.

However, `applicationLogic` is being called before `tasks` is completed.
How do I force the `applicationLogic` method to be blocked until `tasks` is complete?

The error that I'm getting is

> An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Comment: yes, of course.  `asyncio.wait` is itself a co-routine, and have to be awaited - with the `await` keyword, and, as such, needs to be inside an `async def`ed method.

Comment: Thanks, @jsbueno! This did indeed resolve the error, which I was facing. Now however, the applicationLogic method is starting before tasks is completed. What I'd like is to return to the world of synchronous logic once tasks is complete. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Check the docs on ayncio.wait - and asyncio.gather and TaskGroups (py 3.11 only) - any of the three have ways to run and just allow the code to proceed all tasks are complete. The default value of `return_when` for asyncio.wait should be what you want. Are you storing the results of your tasks? (it may not show up in the minimal code above)

Comment: but in the code, "as is", the "result" awaited by your tasks is simply thrown away, as you don't loop through the returned tasks in `asyncio.wait` to do anything with the values.

Comment: Good catch, no IRL these pulls are stored as class objects. Originally, I had no used the async or await keywords in aws_wrapper. However, that triggered the original error that you responded to. Agreed that asyncio.wait is probably (one of the) right approaches, but that's where I started.